# Alternative to using custom WP_object in wordpress for a plugin

Tags: wordpress

I may be doing a word press site in future with a simple property website. Having coming across using custom WP_objects my concern is search querying is a little slow due to wordpress db structure (lots of sql queries). Is there anyway I can create my own custom tables with content and plug that in to wordpress for the properties please?

It would be nice if I could create a admin section for these properties along with some form of custom pages that do not need to be created with in the pages section of wordpress.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)